# List View: Create a department owned accounts List View

Tags: lightning-experience, list-view

I am trying to find a way to create a List View of Account object in Salesforce Lightning Experience that shows all the records owned by me and my group/team/department. And the list changes based on my group/team/department.

For example, let's say John, Alex and I are in the same sales team in US. I want to have this List View to see all the accounts owned by three of us. (And we have all the permissions to see these records.)
On the other hand, another sales team in China can also use this List View to see their team owned account records as well.

Comment: It would be helpful if someone can tell me the reason for downvoting this question.

Comment: This is pure speculation since I did not downvote, but It is likely because the downvoter felt that you had not shown any effort to achieve what you are asking for, since part of the makeup of SFSE culture is seen in the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center where, among other things, it says, "Your question should include...(the code, metadata, or design, in its current form). and/or the research and work you’ve done so far on the issue."

Comment: @Moonpie Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

- Create new List view E.g. "My Department Accounts" share this view
  with intended set of users based on public groups/roles/roles and
  internal subordinates.
- Go to Setting of created list view > Edit List Filters > Filtered By = My account teams
- Add Users on Account team. E.g John, Alex and you will be on all US accounts.

If US Sales Reps don't need access to China Sales Reps Account & vice versa then, other way is to keep org wide default private and create Roles as Sales Rep US, Sales Rep China. Create Owner based sharing rules based on role. In All Accounts list view you will be able to see Accounts of users who are on Sales same role as you.